# Функция build_absolute_uri всегда генерит http

Tags: python, django, url, request

Функция build_absolute_uri у обьекта request генерит url с  протоколом http,хотя явно url с протоколом https.Можно ли как-то заставить генерить защитный протокол?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Из документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri)

> Mixing HTTP and HTTPS on the same site is discouraged, therefore
> build_absolute_uri() will always generate an absolute URI with the
> same scheme the current request has. If you need to redirect users to
> HTTPS, it’s best to let your Web server redirect all HTTP traffic to
> HTTPS.

Т.е. функция возвращает тот же протокол, который стоит в request

Edit:
Если же ты для сайта используешь оба протокола и хочешь что бы тебе build_absolute_uri всегда формировалась с https, просто заменяй в результирующей строке `request.build_absolute_uri('url').replace('http:', 'https:')`

Comment: Значит вопрос сводится к тому, а почему в request стоит протокол http, если он на самом деле https

Comment: Это не обязательно. Может он тестирует на локальной машине и у него стоит django в качестве веб сервера, следовательно все запросы идут именно через http. Или же его сайт работает и по http и по https, а ему нужно что бы всегда выдавалось именно https.

Comment: В вопросе написано «хотя явно url с протоколом https», а у меня пока что нет причин не доверять автору (хотя допускаю, что он мог коряво сформулировать вопрос)

Comment: да, ты прав, что-то я не внимательно читаю вопрос

Comment: @AndreyMaslov да,в качестве веб-сервера - django,но на локальной машине все нормально,там всё через http,а вот на платформе heroku возникает такая проблема. То есть когда я писал "url явно c https", я имел в виду то, что я вижу протокол в url, а не под капотом, так сказать. Мне сложно как-то сформулировать, потому что я начинающий в питоне и джанго , так что, простите если что)